# Function accept Arguments, command inside function doesnt see it

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Function which accept arguments and create a schedule task remotely.

```
Function CreateDaTask($hostname,$day,$hour,$minute,$ampm){
$time = "$Hour";$time += ":";$time+="$minute$ampm" 
#I think its weird, i need to get something like 03:15AM

#small part i did for testing the arguments
        write-host "Day is $day"
        write-host "time is $time"
        Write-Host "host name is $hostname"
        
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -Credential (Get-Credential) -Scriptblock {
        $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek $day -At $time
        $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "shutdown" -arg '/r /t 0 /f /c "Test"'
        $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupID "BUILTIN\Administrators" -RunLevel Highest
        Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Testik111"  -Trigger $trigger  -Action $action  -Principal $principal -Description "Test" -force
}
}
```

Now when i call it it seems like $Trigger cant get the arguments, i can see them at the output but the error is that it is null:

Day is Monday
time is 03:30PM
host name is iis

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Trigger'. Cannot convert value "New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek
-At " to type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance[]". Error: "Cannot convert value "New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly
-DaysOfWeek  -At " to type "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance". Error: "Specified argument was out of the range of
valid values.
Parameter name: className""
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Register-ScheduledTask], ParameterBindin...mationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Register-ScheduledTask
+ PSComputerName        : iis

I know its something stupid like "" in wrong place but i havent figured out what is needed exactly,
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [scope problem with invoke-command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7#scope-modifiers)

Please don't mind the small formatting changes

```
Function CreateDaTask($hostname,$day,$hour,$minute,$ampm){
$time = "$Hour";$time += ":";$time+="$minute$ampm" 
#I think its weird, i need to get something like 03:15AM

#small part i did for testing the arguments
    write-host "Day is $day"
    write-host "time is $time"
    Write-Host "host name is $hostname"
    
    # When doing an invoke command, you can't innately use variables from the local scope, you have to specify that you're getting that variable elsewhere
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -Credential (Get-Credential) -Scriptblock {
        # here, you're using $day and $time, which were instantiated in the local scope
        # $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek $day -At $time
        
        # do this instead
        $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek $using:day -At $using:time

        $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "shutdown" -arg '/r /t 0 /f /c "Test"'
        $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupID "BUILTIN\Administrators" -RunLevel Highest
        Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Testik111"  -Trigger $trigger  -Action $action  -Principal $principal -Description "Test" -force
    }
}
```

This is why you see `"Cannot convert value "New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek -At "` notice how there's no values after `-DaysOfWeek` and `-At` in the error message.